# Should I prefer path.display() over debug {:?} formatting?

Tags: rust

Is there any performance hit when using the first?

Is it possible that some characters will be displayed improperly when using the second?

Comment: Interesting question, try to write a test program and measure if you can observe any performance impacts. My guess would be if debug prints are an performance issue for a project you would remove all of them.

Comment: The purpose of both are not the same, they do not return the same values; you're comparing apples and oranges

Comment: Depends on why you're printing the paths. If you want to pipe them to other commands you probably should write the raw bytes to stdout since paths can contain non-unicode byte sequences.

Comment: @the8472 They do not print the same thing. In particular, `Debug` (`{:?}` in prints) wraps everything it prints that isn't a language construct in quotes.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld I said nothing about using `Debug`. I said *write the raw bytes*. This requires platform-specific code: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/index.html#conversions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As explained in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.display), `Path::display` is for safely printing paths that may contain non-Unicode data.

`Debug` preserves those characters, but is not meant to be presented to the end-user. Also, `Debug` surrounds the path with quotes.

For example on Linux:

```rust
use std::path::Path;
use std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt;
use std::ffi::OsStr;

fn main() {
    let path = OsStr::from_bytes(b"./foo/bar\xff.txt");
    let path = Path::new(path);

    println!("{}", path.display()); // ./foo/bar�.txt
    println!("{:?}", path); // "./foo/bar\xFF.txt"
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=284e39d6f0a67ccfb40ba76da3a58041))