# How do I print an OsStr without the quotes?

Tags: rust, formatting

I'm trying to create a new name for a file path. Everything works okay, *except* that when I try to format `OsStr`s, it automatically puts them in quotes. This has been driving me crazy for hours, and no matter whether I use `{:?}` formatting or `{:#?}`, it doesn't change a thing. I also tried using `.unwrap().to_str()`, but that output is even worse. Does anyone know how to get rid of these quotes?

Here is my code:

```rust
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("/home/user/test/something.txt");
    let mut pathbuf = path.to_path_buf();
    pathbuf.set_file_name(&format!(
        "{:?}_{}.{:?}",
        path.file_stem().unwrap(),
        4,
        path.extension().unwrap()
    ));

    println!("{}", pathbuf.display());
}
```

This is the current output:

```
/home/user/test/"something"_4."txt"
```

But what I need it to be:

```
/home/user/test/something_4.txt
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [In Rust should I prefer path.display() over debug {:?} formatting trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57944423/155423); [How to join std::ffi::os_str::OsStr and str?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59559434/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I'd probably [use `OsString`](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2202ba589009f09f5fa62791de25a37e), however.

Comment: Those linked questions, especially the second one, are close to the mark, but I don't see anything in the answers that I haven't already tried. Also, how do I convert `OsStr` to `OsString`? The return value of `file_stem()` and `extension()` is an `OsStr`.

Comment: If you look at @Shepmaster's playground link, you see that there is no need to convert, there is [push](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.push).  If you really need to convert, it is as simple as [to_os_string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.to_os_string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OsStr` implements the `Debug` trait, but not `Display`, I think because `OsStr` is not guaranteed to be valid UTF-8.   The [`OsStr::to_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.to_str) method does what you want.

```
pathbuf.set_file_name(&format!(
    "{}_{}.{}",
    path.file_stem().unwrap().to_str().unwrap(),
    4,
    path.extension().unwrap().to_str().unwrap(),
));
```

Comment: I still [maintain that using a `&str` is improper here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70266860/how-do-i-print-an-osstr-without-the-quotes?noredirect=1#comment124212854_70266860), as you needlessly prevent non-UTF-8 text.

Comment: @Shepmaster If you have an alternative answer, please write it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is a good idea to manipulate filenames, paths and `&OsStr` in general with `format!`, because that requires you to convert to `String` with `.to_str()`, which will fail and break your code if provided with invalid unicode filenames, which unfortunately, are quite common, specially in languages that are written in almost-ASCII, but uses a few non-ASCII characters, like á, ß, ç, ø, ü, etc..., making it easy to overlook errors in conversion between different character encondings).

The robust way to do what OP wants is to create a mutable `OsString` and manually push to it:

```rs
fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("/home/user/test/something.txt");

    let new_file_name = {
        let mut filename = path.file_stem().unwrap().to_owned();
        filename.push(format!("_{}", 4));
        filename.push(path.extension().unwrap());
        filename
    };

    let mut pathbuf = path.to_path_buf();
    pathbuf.set_file_name(new_file_name);

    println!("{}", pathbuf.display());
}
```